# Can you please explain this error?

Tags: c#, list

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Parts>'
```

Below is the code generating this error. I am pretty sure I am doing something silly.

```
public class Parts
{


public string computername { get; set; }


public List<Parts> GetParts()
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>(); 
   //The object that will physically connect to the database 
   using(SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["request"].ConnectionString))  
   { 
            //The SQL you want to execute 
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM REQUESTS", cnx); 
           //Open the connection to the database 
           cnx.Open(); 
           //execute your command 
           SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
           { 
             //Loop through your results 
             while(dataReader.Read()) 
             { 
                lst.Add(Convert.ToString(dataReader["titlename"])); 
             } 
           } 
   } 
   return lst; 
} 

}
```

The error keeps pointing to this line:

```
   return lst;
```

Thank you

Comment: I suspect the error you're getting tells you what's wrong; mismatch in the return type.

Comment: Although many people have already pointed out the correct reason why you get the error message, I just wanted to add that it's often times a better choice to return the Interface definition instead of the specific class. Meaning your GetParts() should return IList<Parts> instead of List<Parts> - this allows for example for better testability through mocking (i.e. implement your own class that implements IList<Parts> and use that in your code)

Comment: Oooh, that is misleading. It's been a while since I got one of those errors from c#, so I've forgotten.

Comment: @AndrewHagner Actually, the OP hadn't formatted the question correctly. The error message did include the `<string>` and `<Parts>` (it was in the source of the question, but they were being treated as invalid HTML tags, so they were not displayed)

Comment: Ah I see, I had that problem with my answer too

Comment: I believe you are right @AndrewB. I will get better as I have better understanding of c# and vb. Thanks again all for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of method GetParts() is `List<Parts>`, but in function, you try to return a `List<string>`

try this:

```
public List<Parts> GetParts()
{
    List<Parts> lst = new List<Parts>(); 
    using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["request"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM REQUESTS", cnx);
        cnx.Open();
        Parts parts = null; 
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        { 
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                parts = new Parts();
                parts.computername = dataReader["titlename"].ToString();
                lst.Add(parts);
            }
        }
    }
    return lst;
} 

public void SomeMethod(List<Parts> parts)
{
    List<string> title = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in parts)
    {
        title.Add(item.titlename);
    }
    this.ddlPartsTitle.Datasource = title;
    this.ddlPartsTitle.DataBind();
}

public YourClassName()
{
    this.SomeMethod(this.GetParts());
}
```

Comment: All of you guys sound alike which tells me you guys know your stuff. Impressive>

I suspected I knew what was wrong but could not fix it.

I tried changing this: List<string> to List<Parts> but kept getting the same error. That tells you I am a noob.

Thanks ALL for your rapdi response.

Comment: just one more question even though I have accepted the answer, please? All we are interested in is returning just the titlename. However, when I click the view results, I get out of range error. I suppose I am getting this error because I didn't have any ID bound. Can we work around ID since we don't want to display it?

Comment: @ChidiOkeh: Would you please explain more about error? Do you want to bind a datacontrol to GetParts() or some like this?

Answer (score 10):

You are returning a `List<string>` when the method return type is `List<Part>`.

Answer (score 5):

Your method wants to return a `List<Parts>`, but you're trying to return a `List<string>`

Answer (score 5):

```
List<string> is not the same as List<Parts>
```

You are trying to return a list of the wrong type. Your method declaration:

```
public List<Parts> GetParts()
```

Specifies that you return a:

```
List<Parts>
```

However you are returning:

```
List<string>
```

To correct, you should either make the list within your function a `List<Parts>` and add `Parts` to it. Or change the return type to `List<string>`

A simple error, I've made it a few times myself.

Answer (score 5):

The error occurs because the method should return a `List<Parts>` and you try to return a `List<string>`

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to return a `List<string>` from a function that returns `List<Parts>`.

The type of the return value of the function and the type of what you're returning need to match.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a SELECT to transform the list of strings to a list of parts.

Assuming you had a Parts class like so

```
class Parts{
    string TitleName { get; set; }
    public Parts(){ }

}
```

You could do `return lst.Select( str => new Parts(){ TitleName = str });`

Comment: You guys are fantastic. I truly appreciate all the help and the really quick response. It is working now. Unfortunately, I can only check the checkmark for only one help.